# while loop is assigning value to variable and which i will be using later but not sure about

Tags: shell

```
read -p "Enter the new Kernel Destination: " kernel_new
n=1

while [ "$word" != "no" ]
do
read -p "Enter the Hostname: " hostname_$n
read -p "Enter the SID: " sid_$n
read -p "Enter the destination of Kernel: " kernel_old_$n
read -p "Want to add new entry please give yes or else give no: " word
n=$(( n+1 ))
done

echo "Kernel Upgrade is starting now"

while [ $n != 0 ]
do
echo "Upgrading ${hostname_[$n]} "
n=$(( n-1 ))
done
```

Execution:

I want to display the "Upgrading hostname" where hostname will be assigned in my first while loop during the user prompt. So suppose hostname_1 =abcdef, hostname_2=qwerty

Then i want output as

```
Upgrading abcdef
Upgrading qwerty
```

Please help!!!!!

Shell

```
while [ $n != 0 ]
do
echo "Upgrading ${hostname_[$n]} "
n=$(( n-1 ))
done
```

I want to display the "Upgrading hostname" where hostname will be assigned in my first while loop during the user prompt. So suppose

```
hostname_1 =abcdef, hostname_2=qwerty
```

Then i want output as

```
Upgrading abcdef
Upgrading qwerty
```

Please help!!!!!

Comment: Try `n_host="hostname_$n";echo "Upgrading ${!n_host}"`

Comment: Note `shell` does not have arrays, e.g. `${hostname_[$n]}`. What shell do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are captured within the while loop in a subshell and are not available outside. But you can try it with an associative array. Here is a simplified example of how it might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare an associative array
declare -A dict
n=0
while true; do
    read -r -p "Hostname: " dict['hostname_'$n]
    read -r -p "retry? (Yn): " answer
    [[ "$answer" == "n" ]] && break
    (( n++ ))
done 

# loop over all entries in reverse order
for i in $(seq $n -1 0); do
    printf "%s\n" "${dict['hostname_'$i]}"
done
```

Comment: I want to count number of lines in a files and assign that integer to a variable. I am using below code but not able to get through

Shell

!/bin/bash
file=hostname.txt n= $( wc -l hostname.txt | awk '{ print $1 }' ) #assigning number of lines to a variable but not able to do so i=1 while read -r line do while [ $i -le $n ] do echo "==============$i=================$n================================"

i=$((i+1)) done done < "$file"

==============1=================2================================ ==============2=================2================================

shell